# Check elements in IEnumerable<string> sequence for specific string

Tags: c#

```
    foreach (string s in diff.InSecondNotInFirst)
    {
        if (!s.Contains("some text"))
        {
            Assert.Fail();
        }
    }
```

Can I do this without the foreach? `diff.InSecondNotInFirst` is `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: With Linq you can do something like: `if (diff.InSecondNotInFirst.Any(s => !s.Contains("some text"))) Assert.Fail();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Linq you can do something like:

```
if (diff.InSecondNotInFirst.Any(s => !s.Contains("some text")))
  Assert.Fail();
```

Comment: Actually, it doesn't make a difference. It's just for readability.

Comment: How can I use `s` in the condition body? Thank you.

Comment: You can't. If you need to then stick with the `foreach` loop.